# ApigatewayV2 HttpApi as target for Eventbridge

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-event-bridge

EventBridge supports targeting APIGateway API as an event target. But `aws-events-targets` package only supports v1-style `RestApi` [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/a35fcc59b227cc6151c50ebd04a7b9f9fb3bc189/packages/aws-cdk-lib/aws-events-targets/lib/api-gateway.ts). I would like to use v2-style `HttpApi` as the event target.

Use Case:

Creating private integration from Apigateway to an ALB is now super convenient with `aws-apigatewayv2-integrations-alpha` but I would need to connect that APIgw `HttpApi` to EventBridge target.

I wonder if I should just use the `url` of the `HttpApi` as `ApiDestination` instead of hoping to use the target.ApiGateway? Or is there a simple way to implement `HttpApi` support for a Eventbridge target?

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar. It seems like AWS EventBridge doesn't support HTTP APIs (v2) yet. You could use the HTTP target URL directly but I think you have to make the endpoint public for that to work. In my case, we want it to be private with IAM auth. Haven't found a good solution yet. Maybe [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/sending-amazon-eventbridge-events-to-private-endpoints-in-a-vpc/)